# Firefox shortcut with querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox, shortcut

I'm having the following issue when trying to create a shortcut to firefox.

When the browser launches, it should automatically go to a url of the following type: www.website.com/login.aspx?username=user

But, as soon as the browser opens, it gets directed to www.website.com/login.aspxusername=user. So we are loosing the question mark in the target.

I tried the same with an extra "/" ex. www.website.com/login.aspx/user but this also fails. I am redirected to www.website.co/login.aspxuser.

The shortcut was created with the following parameterization: 
target => C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "http://www.website.com/login.aspx?username=user"

Can anybody help me with this? I'm open to all sugestions.

Comment: have you tried escaping the ? how are you calling firefox (btw just use "firefox.exe" instead of the direct path

Comment: Tried with firefox.exe instead of the path, but that did not fix it. Any tips about how to escape the ? in the shortcut target. I have no clue how I would escape the ?.

Comment: It wouldn't fix it that was just a different bug fix for you.. You haven't said how you are calling your process

Comment: I just created a shortcut on the desktop that points to firefox with a given url.